# How to reproduce charcoal flavor in steaks and burgers from restaurants

Tags: meat, flavor

Recently I went to a couple of restaurants. I had a burger at one and a steak at the other, both had a distinct taste that I can't describe. Kind of a charcoal taste but I know they were cooked over an open flame. I tried liquid smoke but that didn't work. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Burn them a bit, use more salt.

Comment: Open flame from gas fire? Or open flame from wood fire? Often times wood fire imparts smokey flavors unique to the wood burned.

Comment: I may be the condensed vapor from the burning of the grease dripping from the meat being cooked. Cooking with gas over Lava rocks could verify that.

Comment: One of the best burgers I ever had was from a place in the mall, years ago. I found out the cook never, ever cleaned the griddle. Every burger carried with it the charred remains of its ancestors. It tasted a lot like a charcoal burger.